# How can I animate one single item (entry) after the List is already updated and drawn?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity, android-animation

I have this main ListView (retrieved using `this.getListView()`) in a ListActivity properly populated from a SQLite database. A click on one of its items (entries) calls another activity A2 using `startActivityForResult()`. I would like to animate that SINGLE entry WHEN the user gets back to the ListActivity. (So I suppose I need to override the `onActivityResult()` method)

How can I animate a single entry once the window gained focus and after the list is updated using `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

I managed to animate the whole ListView using

```
getListView().setAnimation(anim)
```

and worked fine. However, when I do:

```
getListView().getChildAt(position).setAnimation(anim)
```

nothing happens.

**EDIT**: Here's my onActivityResult code

```
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent intent) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==SOME_REQUEST_CODE){

        Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f,0.0f);  
        anim.setFillAfter(true);  
        anim.setDuration(400); 
        anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        anim.setRepeatCount(7);
        // Just for testing, I chose the first item of the ListView (position=0)
        tr_adapter.getView(0, getListView().getChildAt(0), getListView()).setAnimation(anim);

        tr_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //Nothing happens

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a flag in your table and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your list adapter. Have `getView()` in your list adapter determine what to do (animate or not) based on the flag in your table. I'd post some sample code but I'm mobile.

EDIT

---

In your `onActivityResult()`, flag (with some value, boolean, 1/0, etc) the data point in your data set that you'd like to animate. Then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter. Assuming you have a custom list adapter, have your `getView()` function flip the animation on or off (or default to off and flip it on given the flag).

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    // All the standard getView() stuff

    if (listitem.shouldAnimate())
        // animate
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jsimon, but I didn't really understand your method. It would be great if you could leave an example.

Comment: hint: "Assuming you have a custom list adapter ... ".   If you don't have a custom list adapter then you will need to create one so that you can add your animation code in the getView(...) method as described above.    Look at this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Thanks Akos Cz ! (Sorry for replying so late)

Comment: Sorry jsimon I didn't notice your EDIT, I already did as you suggested, thanks !