# Animating New ListView Item

Tags: android, listview, animation

I have an activity that contains two listviews. When I click on one of the lists, the item clicked is removed from that list and added to the other list. I'm trying to provide some animations on this process.

I can successfully animate the removal of the existing item in the initial list. However, I cannot yet animate the insertion of the new item into the other list. I get an NPE error when I try to start the animation on the new list item.

```
lvAvailableVenues.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Venue venue = availableVenues.get(position);

        availableVenues.remove(position);
        availableVenuesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        slideOutRight(position);

        lvSelectedVenues.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
        selectedVenues.add(availableVenues.get(position));
        Collections.sort(selectedVenues, new Venue.VenueComparator());
        selectedVenuesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        slideInLeft(venue.getVenueId());
    }
});

private void slideOutRight(int position) {
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(VenueFilterActivity.this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    anim.setDuration(500);
    lvAvailableVenues.getChildAt(position).startAnimation(anim );
}

private void slideInLeft(int venueId) {

    for (int i=0; i<selectedVenues.size(); i++) {
        if (selectedVenues.get(i).getVenueId() == venueId) {
            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(VenueFilterActivity.this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            anim.setDuration(500);
            // this is the line that crashes!!!
            lvSelectedVenues.getChildAt(i).startAnimation(anim);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.view.View.startAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)' on
>   a null object reference

Note that if I comment out the offending line, then my list is updated correctly, but without the animation that I am trying to create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly advice you to move to RecylerView which has default ItemAnimator that handles different types of animations per-se insert/delete/update - it is far more efficient as well. Once you get to know how it functions it is a lot easier to implement.

> [How to animate RecyclerView items when they appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724964/how-to-animate-recyclerview-items-when-they-appear)

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, `lvSelectedVenues.getChildAt(i)` is returing null. This is probably because the child view you are trying to get is not currently visible, therefore returning null.

Check out these questions, their answers might help you: [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096044/how-can-i-animate-one-single-item-entry-after-the-list-is-already-updated-and), [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264795/animate-newly-added-items-in-listview)

You can use `RecyclerView` as an alternative and it already includes animations. [Here is an example of that](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview).